# How do I update javascript variables with new values which are changing in my database?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database

I'm building a multiplayer game which uses a mysql database to store coordinate positions of players, which are then used to display opponent models.

The game uses a javascript file (milktruck.js) on the client side, and then a php file (xml_http_request.php) on the server side.

My problem occurs when trying to get the javascript variables (which store the coordinate information of an opponent) updated as the database information is updated.

The javascript variables are declared within the php file with the following code:

```
  echo "<script> var lla0php = $lla0; </script>";
  echo "<script> var lla1php = $lla1; </script>";
  echo "<script> var lla2php = $lla2; </script>";
```

Then used in the javascript file, ticking function: prototype.tick, with:

```
  window['lla0_2']= lla0php;
  window['lla1_2']= lla1php;
  window['lla2_2']= lla2php;
```

How do I continuously update these variables with new database information?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that as well

Answer (score 0):

The web model is stateless, and to do this you're going to have to think of a way to overcome this and may possibly consider writing an abstraction layer that takes care of this for you.

You'll either need to poll continuously or look into other web-based solutions that allow the server to "push" data back to the client and maintain an "open channel" of communication. An example of this would be Google Talk in your browser or FaceBook chat.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use ajax.

```
function requestCoord(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "your url",
        dataType : "json",
        type: "GET",
        success(val){
            //get your php script to echo out a json string 
                        //and it will be in val
            window['lla0_2']= val.lla0php;
            window['lla1_2']= val.lla1php;
            window['lla2_2']= val.lla2php;

        }
    });
}

setInterval(requestCoord, 1000);
```

### UPDATE

You can use [html5 sockets.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262543/what-are-good-resources-for-learning-html-5-websockets)

Comment: @user671891: @locrizak provides a good basic example of what I mentioned in polling continuously for updates. In this sample the update frequency is one second. You need to decide if this will be enough. Also, with AJAX- (not a "continually open communication channel", so to speak), you will only be able to make so many requests per second. Should you need to simulate motion, you may also need to interpolate between stale and new data to give the impression of movement rather than an entity (enemy) "teleporting" to their new location.

Comment: @KTF Yeah that doesn't make sense, I had a brain fart. I think you should look into html5 sockets. Ive posted the link in my answer.

Comment: With the ajax solution, could you tell me step by step how to implement that. Would the code you provided go within the javascript file, then requestCoord() would be called within the tick function? How would I get my php script to echo out a json string? Would I have to add any files to my hosting server to allow ajax to operate? When you mention html5 sockets, would those just be a better solution, or would the above ajax solution not work?

Comment: @user671891 The html5 sockets would be a far better way to accomplish this just because its built in and you don't have to grab the values every second( or however often you want to grab it) I don't have any experience in using html5 sockets but the link provided has more than enough info to get you on your way.